# Grouping list elements with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a little trouble comming up with a LINQ expression for some grouping I´d like to do.
I have a big list of maybe a few thousand mails that have to be sent and I´d like to group them into lists of 2000 mails and put these into a parent list. 
The original list looks like this: `List<Recipient>()`

Recipients have a Name, Address etc.

I have written what I want to do with a foreach, but if possible I´d like to have it as a LINQ expression, I just can´t seem to figure it out.

```
private List<List<Recipient>> PhysicalPageList(List<Recipient> recipients)
    {
        var pageList = new List<List<Recipient>>();
        var smallList = new List<Recipient>();
        foreach (var rec in recipients) 
        {
            smallList.Add(rec);
            if (smallList.Count % 2000 == 0) { continue; }
            var tmpList = new List<Recipient>();
            tmpList.AddRange(smallList);
            pageList.Add(smallList);
            smallList.Clear();
        }
        if (smallList.Count() != 0)
        {
            var tmpList = new List<Recipient>();
            tmpList.AddRange(smallList);
            pageList.Add(tmpList);
            smallList.Clear();
        }

        return pageList;
    }
```

I have an example of this with strings and not Recipients (havent written this myself):

```
    private List<List<string>> PageList(List<string> recipients)
    {
        return recipients.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                                        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2000) 
                                        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                                        .ToList();
    }
```

I tried the same but LINQ wouldn´t let me select from the list of Recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't try this one?

```
private List<List<Recipient>> PageList(List<Recipient> recipients)
{
    return recipients.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2000) 
                     .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                     .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just realised that as well ... I dont know where I went wrong the first time, but now it works...

Comment: @Todtaure thanks dude ! it happens sometimes. I am glad that I helped.